# "has been completed" or "is completed"?

Tags: word-choice, present-perfect, present-simple

> Repeat the steps for the next weekly report until the monthly report
>   **has been** completed.
>
> Repeat the steps for the next weekly report until the monthly report
>   **is** completed.

I'm having a hard time choosing which is correct. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: **The present perfect emphasizes slightly more that there was a process that led to the completion of the report**, while the present simple merely states the fact that it is indeed completed. That said, I think they're virtually equivalent due to the fact that the verb *completed* in itself means some acquired state. Further, the second example is clearly ambiguous as to whether *completed* is an adjective or verb. If it's the latter, the passive construction leans towards completion, while the adjective describes the acquired state. To sum up, the only real difference is stated in bold.

Answer (score 2):

Your two examples

> Repeat the steps for the next weekly report until the monthly report **has been** completed.
>
> Repeat the steps for the next weekly report until the monthly report **is** completed.

are essentially equivalent both saying to complete the monthly report.

A slight nuance might be that since *perfect tenses* imply an ordering of events, your first example leaves the listener expecting something else might happen ***after the monthly process is finished***.